# how to get soap response from webServiceTemplate

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-ws

I need to get a soap response using "webServiceTemplate". Currently in my existing architecture it's using function "public boolean sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(String uri, Source requestPayload, Result responseResult) {
           } " but this is returning only boolean value, but is there any way to capture the soap response?

I tried with "marshalSendAndReceive" functions but its not working.

Could you please suggest how can I get the soap response using webServiceTemplate functions, or will I have to write a customized function for this ?

Thank You !

Comment: If you edit the question to have some formatting for the code I will upvote :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream  bytArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bytArrayOutputStream);

wsTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(defautUri, source, result); 

final String reply = new String(bytArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

Comment: @user3365075 If it did, please mark VirtualTroll's answer as correct!